# Set a periodic notification in android

Tags: android, notifications

i am trying to create a periodic notification in android, and i have almost achieved it, the problem is that with my code it opens the app instead of creating the notification, here is my code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
           new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                   .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                   .setContentTitle(this.getText(R.string.notificationMessage))
                   .setContentText("")
                   .setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    // Because clicking the notification opens a new ("special") activity, there's
    // no need to create an artificial back stack.
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
           PendingIntent.getActivity(
                   this,
                   0,
                   resultIntent,
                   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
           );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotifyMgr.notify(1,mBuilder.build());


    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 07);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, resultPendingIntent);  //set repeating every 24 hours
```

UPDATED CODE:

class Main Activity:

```
PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, NotificationService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 20);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, servicePendingIntent);  //set repeating every 24 hours
```

class NotificationService:

```
public class NotificationService extends IntentService {

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public NotificationService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Log.d("NotificationService", "onHandleIntent");

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(this.getText(R.string.notificationMessage))
                        .setContentText("")
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        // Because clicking the notification opens a new ("special") activity, there's
        // no need to create an artificial back stack.
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        resultIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotifyMgr.notify(1,mBuilder.build());



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the pending intent for the activity into the alarm manager.  You'll need to move the notification code to a service (I'd recommend an IntentService).

Then you can need to create a pending intent that runs that service and pass that pending intent into the alarm manager.  This way every time the alarm goes off, your notification code is run.

```
PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(this, NotificationService.class));
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, servicePendingIntent);
```

Comment: I have moved all the notification code to a new class as you said and created the PendingIntent with getService (it required me a FLAG so i have tried with  FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT) but it isn't calling the new class, i do not know why.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like it should work.  Did you add the `NotificationService` to your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: I did'n because it isn't an activity and when i wrote the code to start only one notification it didn't required it, so how should i add it to the manifest now?

Comment: i just saw a warning in the log cat that says: Unable to start service Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=com.labs.thirsty.example/.NotificationService (has extras) } U=0: not found

Comment: Finally achieved!!! I add it to the manifest but it was complaining with the constructor created by android studio so i had to chane it. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `PendingIntent` points to your activity. You just need to use `PendingIntent.getService` instead, and have this service showing your notification.